# WPBakery Page Builder causes 403 forbidden error

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-403

I am using WPBakery Page Builder for my wordpress website. Everytime I update a page that is using WPBakery, it shows "403 Forbidden - Access to this resource on the server is denied!". I can't figure out why and I really need help

Comment: You should try and reach out to WP Bakery support. We really can't help without seeing server error logs.

Comment: 2020-08-27 11:15:33.313795 [INFO] [23432] [xx.xxx.xxx.xx:62573:HTTP2-11#APVH_new.irinavoinea.com:443] File not found [/home/irinavoi/new.irinavoinea.com/403.shtml]

Answer (score 0):

check with the mod security on your server and deactivate it for your domain and this will fix the error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Resolved it when I disabled Slider Revolution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).